# Team Project in Visual basic 2010,2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm new to stack overflow.
I learnt visual basic 6.0 on my own(with the help of the internet) And i migrated to vb2010 and next to vb 2012.now my question is how to work in a team with my friend(s) in a same project(without spending any extra money exept the internet cost(my father wont give me money)).my friend is in a distant place.

---

can anyone help me to solve this problem.
anyone who can help me are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a good version control system, I would recommend a GIT e.g.: http://git-scm.com

> Git is a free and open source distributed version control system
>   designed to handle everything from small to very large projects with
>   speed and efficiency.
>
> Git is easy to learn and has a tiny footprint with lightning fast
>   performance. It outclasses SCM tools like Subversion, CVS, Perforce,
>   and ClearCase with features like cheap local branching, convenient
>   staging areas, and multiple workflows.

Alternative you can use SVN as well, here the comparison of both systems: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison

> Git is much faster than Subversion Subversion allows you to check out
>   just a subtree of a repository; Git requires you to clone the entire
>   repository (including history) and create a working copy that mirrors
>   at least a subset of the items under version control. Git's
>   repositories are much smaller than Subversions (for the Mozilla
>   project, 30x smaller) Git was designed to be fully distributed from
>   the start, allowing each developer to have full local control Git
>   branches are simpler and less resource heavy than Subversion's Git
>   branches carry their entire history Merging in Git does not require
>   you to remember the revision you merged from (this benefit was
>   obviated with the release of Subversion 1.5) Git provides better
>   auditing of branch and merge events Git's repo file formats are
>   simple, so repair is easy and corruption is rare. Backing up
>   Subversion repositories centrally is potentially simpler - since you
>   can choose to distributed folders within a repo in git Git repository
>   clones act as full repository backups Subversion's UI is more mature
>   than Git's Walking through versions is simpler in Subversion because
>   it uses sequential revision numbers (1,2,3,..); Git uses unpredictable
>   SHA-1 hashes. Walking backwards in Git is easy using the "^" syntax,
>   but there is no easy way to walk forward.

Comment: Ok,But what is GIT and what's version control system?.I don't know anything about team foundation server(except that i could work with a team).If you can make me a tutorial.Please do it for me.

Comment: With pleasure: http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/ Take a look!

Comment: The comparison is not really fair according to http://svnvsgit.com/. Have you ever tried comparing svn vs git  side by side yourself?

Comment: I use both of them side-by-side (SmartGIT and Tortoise SVN)